# SSRS Removing "#Error" from a tablix

Tags: reporting-services, error-handling

I have a problem which I would love some help with.

I am displaying various results in a Table, by month. Not every month has data in it. I want one particular parameter to have 4 decimal places and all of the rest to have two decimal places. I have prepared the following code.

=IIF(Fields!Test_Name.Value.Contains("Iron content"), Format(Fields!DecimalValue.Value,"F4"), Format(Fields!DecimalValue.Value,"F2")     )

The only problem is, the unpopulated months display
 #Error in them.
 Is there a way to remove the #Error message these cells and return them to being blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the value is non null and then apply the format the following will show the 0 instead of empty space in null value cells. You can use the `IIF` outside and make it to show up empty if you want.

```
  =IIF(Fields!Test_Name.Value.Contains("Iron content"),   
   Format(
     IIF(IsNothing(Fields!DecimalValue.Value),0,Fields!DecimalValue.Value)
     ,"F4")
  ,Format(IIF(IsNohting(Fields!DecimalValue.Value),0,Fields!DecimalValue.Value)
     ,"F2") 
    )
```